# Angular ui-router 1.0.3 reloadOnSearch equivalent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I recently upgraded to UI-router v1.0.3 from v0.3.2.  It seems as though reloadOnSearch has been removed from the stateConfig.

What is the equivalent of reloadOnSearch in v1.0.3?  I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

The documentation seems to indicate it was removed in v0.2.5 (but I was using it in v0.3.2)

> **reloadOnSearch v0.2.5**
>
> Boolean (default true). If false will not retrigger the same state just because a search/query parameter has changed. Useful for when you'd like to modify $location.search() without triggering a reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic params.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html

From the doc

> When dynamic is true, changes to the parameter value will not cause the state to be entered/exited. The resolves will not be re-fetched, nor will views be reloaded.
>
> Normally, if a parameter value changes, the state which declared that the parameter will be reloaded (entered/exited). When a parameter is dynamic, a transition still occurs, but it does not cause the state to exit/enter.
>
> This can be useful to build UI where the component updates itself when the param values change. A common scenario where this is useful is searching/paging/sorting.

Comment: Stepan, do you know if there is a way to only have a parameter be dynamic for a particular child state?


I have a abstract parent state that defines my state parameters for 3 child states.  2 of those child states I want the parameter to not be dynamic and 1 I would like it to be dynamic.  You could easily do this before with reloadOnSearch:false

Comment: Sorry, I did not encounter such a problem. Try to override the parameter in the child state. I hope this helps.